# Convert json to xml - using java

Tags: java

I'm new at java so i have a problem with my java-code. The result of the code is to get a xml file with formatting.

This is my Java code:

```
import java.io.*;
import com.github.tsohr.JSONArray;
import com.github.tsohr.JSONException;
import com.github.tsohr.JSONObject;
import com.github.tsohr.XML;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;



    public class WriteToFile {       
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception  {   
String path = new String(args[0]) ;             
String xmlStr =new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path))("UTF-8"));
             System.out.println(xmlStr);
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(xmlStr);
           String finalStr = XML.toString(jsonObject);
                System.out.println(finalStr);
                    System.out.println("done");         
                    FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(args[1]); 
                    fw.append("<JSON>");        
                    fw.write(finalStr);         
                    fw.append("</JSON>");           
                    fw.close(); } }
```

This is what i get for example:

```
<car><blue>123</blue><car>
```

And this is what i want to get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
  <car>    
     <blue>123</blue> 
  <car>
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want to print it on separate lines using the `\r\n` character, and also get a description?

Comment: `com.github.tsohr.XML` is very limited. Use JAXB or something instead.

Comment: @FailingCoder yes exactly

Comment: I do believe you can add newline characters to StringBuilder. I don't know about the description though.